# Cisco 2900 series router - 3x 3g HWIC - Can you use the same subnet for each HWIC?

Tags: cisco, 3g

We host a site with a 2900 series router with 3x 3G-HWIC cards installed.

It is hosted with telstra and plugs into our corporate WAN.

The card authenticates against radius and advertises a route into the WAN for which subnet it routes for.

We have always used the same advertised subnet on each.

Telstra have advised us that this could be the cause of some drop out issues whereby some services will work for some people and not for others and are saying effectively that their system will only use one of these at a time even though we can see the interface is online and assigned a WAN IP address.

Has anyone out there configured a multi HWIC setup before and if so are they using different subnets for each or the same?

Comment: How are you advertising your internal subnet to the WAN? BGP?

Comment: This is on a telstra service using APN: Telstra.corp.  Radius assigns a WAN IP address that plugs in to the telstra MPLS and Radius is aware of the internal subnet.